# iPhoto metada to EXIF

Tags: iphoto, export, exif

Is there a way to dump the iPhoto meta-data information, like places (for those pictures without geo-tags themselves), faces (only who is in it would be enough), events and keywords to the pictures themselves as EXIF data, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, no.

Answer (score 2):

[Phoshare](https://sites.google.com/site/phosharedoc/) allows you to export metadata and photos out of iPhoto and will put the data into EXIF tags of the photo.
https://sites.google.com/site/phosharedoc/