# Anyway to tag photos facebook style in native .jpg or .png metadata?

Tags: photos, tags

I've been intrested in this for a while I love the way that facebook tags photos. I think picasa web is a better system but not as easy to use.

I know i can geo-tag my photo files but is there a way to mark who in the photo and where in the photo they are?

Is there any standard way to do this?

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/32528/iphoto-metada-to-exif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While JPG and PNG metadata extensions (EXIF, IPTC, XMP) allows you to key in various information, the problem here is that there is no pre-defined standards on storing the information of who and where in the photo.

As such, there is no standard way of doing this. While I can key in this info "Crash893:500,300,700,100" in a comment field to denote that Crash893 can be found from pixel coordinates x500,y300 to x700,y100 - there is no guarantee that any program can read it.

AFAIK, FB, Picasa, etc does not store all these info inside the image file itself, relying on external referenced databases (XML, SQL, etc) to store these info.

Comment: There is no standard way. For instance, Picasa has no idea what I've tagged in iPhoto, iPhoto has no idea what I've tagged in Picasa. Most programs only know their format. It's not like MP3s, which have the id3v tags more or less standardized.

Comment: @Crash893; Welcome to the wonderful world of "Everyone can make their own system!"